# Vectorised distance function for non-continuous lines

Tags: python, shapely, numpy

I have a function that works out the distance for two countries' shared border, it works fine for any border that is continuous, but (I think) it also adds up empty space between the end of one line and the start of another. (for example, adding the length separating Spain's exclaves when measuring the Spanish-Moroccan border).

```
from shapely import get_parts, get_coordinates
import numpy as np


# Functions
def Distance(geom_input):
     # Average radius of WGS84 spherical Earth model in metres
    R = 6371008.771415

    # Extract coordinates
    coordinates = get_coordinates(get_parts(geom_input))

    # Unpack coordinates into separate latitude and longitude arrays
    latitudes = np.array(coordinates)[:, 0]
    longitudes = np.array(coordinates)[:, 1]

    # Shift arrays to calculate differences between consecutive elements
    latitudes_shifted = np.roll(latitudes, -1)
    longitudes_shifted = np.roll(longitudes, -1)

    # Convert latitude and longitude from degrees to radians
    lat1_rad = np.deg2rad(latitudes)
    lon1_rad = np.deg2rad(longitudes)
    lat2_rad = np.deg2rad(latitudes_shifted)
    lon2_rad = np.deg2rad(longitudes_shifted)

    # Calculate differences in latitude
    dlat = lat2_rad - lat1_rad


    # Spherical law of cosines formula
    slc = np.sin(lon1_rad) * np.sin(lon2_rad) + np.cos(lon1_rad) * np.cos(lon2_rad) * np.cos(dlat)

    # Clip values to handle potential numerical errors
    slc1 = np.clip(slc, -1, 1)

    # Calculate distances
    distances = np.arccos(slc1)
    total_distance = np.sum(distances[:-1]) * R


    return total_distance
```

I think the source of this is the shifted coordinates arrays. I used a for loop previously which worked, but was slower. Can't figure out a solution at the moment.

```
def Distance(geom_input):
  
    # Average radius of WGS84 spherical Earth model in metres
    R = 6371008.771415

    # Define variable to contain lengths
    segment_length = 0

    for line_seg in get_parts(geom_input):
        coords = get_coordinates(line_seg)

        x1 = coords[0][0]
        x2 = coords[1][0]
        y1 = coords[0][1]
        y2 = coords[1][1]

        # Convert to radians
        a = radians(y1)
        b = radians(y2)
        c = radians(x2 - x1)

        # Spherical law of cosines
        x = sin(a) * sin(b) + cos(a) * cos(b) * cos(c)

        segment_length += acos(x) * R

    return segment_length
```

Input value (geom_input)

```
MULTILINESTRING ((-5.398858678999886 35.924503853000076, -5.3897179769998615 35.90204742500002), (-5.3897179769998615 35.90204742500002, -5.378400837999891 35.881686910000084), (-5.378400837999891 35.881686910000084, -5.362897908999884 35.863806865000114), (-5.362897908999884 35.863806865000114, -5.340728318999936 35.847357489000046), (-2.9478246739999463 35.329779364000046, -2.966920125999877 35.313866272), (-2.966920125999877 35.313866272, -2.9637678629999016 35.286219381000095), (-2.9637678629999016 35.286219381000095, -2.9430456139998853 35.2678742480001), (-2.9430456139998853 35.2678742480001, -2.912912563999953 35.27692291900007))
```

Coords for Spanish-Moroccan border (in degrees):

```
coordinates = [[-5.39885868 35.92450385]
 [-5.38971798 35.90204743]
 [-5.38971798 35.90204743]
 [-5.37840084 35.88168691]
 [-5.37840084 35.88168691]
 [-5.36289791 35.86380687]
 [-5.36289791 35.86380687]
 [-5.34072832 35.84735749]
 [-2.94782467 35.32977936]
 [-2.96692013 35.31386627]
 [-2.96692013 35.31386627]
 [-2.96376786 35.28621938]
 [-2.96376786 35.28621938]
 [-2.94304561 35.26787425]
 [-2.94304561 35.26787425]
 [-2.91291256 35.27692292]]
```

From my results, these are the ones with errors, every other border differs slightly from the loop version, but it's so many decimals it doesn't matter.
[image: Table of results]